# Rails: link_to not rendering dynamic text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

In my rails 4 erb view i have this link,

`<%= link_to "Download @served_file.title", "/public/uploads/@served_file.file", :class => "btn" %>`

However, it won't replace `@served_object.title` and `@served_object.file` with the text but just placing those lines inside a `<%= %>` works as expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to interpolate the values into the string.

```
<%= link_to "Download #{@served_file.title}", "/uploads/#{@served_file.file}", :class => "btn" %>
```

Comment: thanks man, only problem is i get `No route matches [GET] "/public/uploads/abstract-3d-digital-art-forms-2560x1440.jpg"` when clicking the link, should i just use send_file?

Comment: where that file is located ? tell me the absolute path. do the `pwd` and tell me name of your rails app.

Comment: the app is __`file-server`__ `/Users/joshburns/Code/file-server/public/uploads/abstract-3d-digital-art-forms-2560x1440.jpg`

Comment: if that is helpful, please mark that above solution as answer. Thanks